# What does "secure" mean from Webpack, devServer proxy?

Tags: security, webpack, proxy, devserver

From the official page from webpack(DevServer),
secure property is written like 'false' with explanation like below:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://other-server.example.com',
        secure: false,
      },
    },
  },
};

In the function, you get access to the request, response, and proxy options.

Return null or undefined to continue processing the request with proxy.
Return false to produce a 404 error for the request.
Return a path to serve from, instead of continuing to proxy the request.
```

my question could be a bit silly,
but does the "secure" property mean that
**Return false to produce a 404 error for the request** ?

I'm just setting those props for the first time,
so it would be better if understood more clearly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`secure: true` means:

> A backend server running on HTTPS with an invalid certificate will not
> be accepted by default.

So if you want to accept invalid (missconfigured, broken cert chain, revoked, etc. ) cert than use `secure: false`

Comment: As you have mentioned, I was using private cert file match to secure:false. Now clearly understood why my web was broken every page - with secure:true. Thanks for your answer!